# dialog not showing in google maps

Tags: html, google-maps, css, google-maps-api-3

I am not able to see the dialog box in the google maps....
i adjusted the width and height of maps but its not working....
is there some other way...
providing my code below....

http://jsfiddle.net/KNPZB/4/embedded/result/

```
<div class="row features">

            <div class="span6">

              <h3>Our office is located at:</h3>
                <p>
                   47653, Lakeview Blvd, Fremont, CA 94538
                </p>
                <p>
                   Ph. (510)-657-8981 | F:(510)-657-8983|E:cs@defie.co
                </p>
                <p>
                   47653, Lakeview Blvd, Fremont, CA 94538
                </p>

            </div>



            <div class="span6">
                <iframe width="265" height="190" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=47657+Lakeview+Blvd.+Fremont,+Ca.+94538&amp;sll=37.472223,-121.931554&amp;sspn=0.008225,0.019569&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=47657+Lakeview+Blvd,+Fremont,+California+94538&amp;z=14&amp;ll=37.472223,-121.931554&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br>
                <small>
                  <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=47657+Lakeview+Blvd.+Fremont,+Ca.+94538&amp;sll=37.472223,-121.931554&amp;sspn=0.008225,0.019569&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=47657+Lakeview+Blvd,+Fremont,+California+94538&amp;z=14&amp;ll=37.472223,-121.931554" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a>
                </small>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: What dialogue box? Do you mean the infowindow when you click on a marker? And do you mean it is not there at all or you can see part of it but it doesn't fit completely?

Comment: yeah i am talking about the info window

Comment: @user2136828 Did I misinterpret your question in my answer, then?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make embedded google map scale according to the size of the browser window.

So try using this: `<iframe width="50%" height="50%"...`

Sitepoint has a good CSS reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/KNPZB/5/embedded/result/ i update din my fiddle but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are planning to fit the information bubble in such a tiny space, since the bubble itself is bigger than your allocated size for the `<iframe>` element.

In any case, what you want to do is keeping the pin in the correct position (look for the `q` and `sll` parameter) but move the center of the map itself a bit down and to the left by fiddling with the **`ll` parameter** (i.e. latitude and longitude).

I have fiddled a bit for you in <kbd>[this demo](http://jsbin.com/idunir/1/edit)</kbd>. 
Just for reference, I pushed your `ll` of just around `+0,0083/+0,0035`. So we are speaking of small amounts.

I also show you the tiniest possible space in which you can fit **both** the pin **and** the info bubble: you need a square of around `260px × 260px`, and even then it fits barely, overlapping with the control. So you might want to give a bit more breathing space to your map, or maybe considering using a **[static map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)**.